# Under what conditions does MnO2 acts as an oxidizing agent?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

It's very strong in acidic medium. Does it have low or nil oxidizing ability in neutral and basic media?

Does heating solid $\ce{MnO2}$ give it better oxidizing properties?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It certainly is  powerful oxidizer when heated! [Thermite can be made with powdered aluminum and $\ce{MnO2}$](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qRKb-ZMjM68), and is *at least* [as spectacular as with $\ce{Fe2O3}$ as the oxidant](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SpantDvWKUM).